# Jekyll inheritance

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I have this following layout, with jekyll 3.7.3;

```
declare A = apple

include file.html > declare A = orange

print A => orange
```

I am confused to how did `A=orange` leaked to the parent layout, in the [jekyll's doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/#layout-metadata), says that the variables assess thru `layout` in the liquid tag. Does this apply to the `include` as well? It makes no sense in where child layout overwritten the parent layout, as it is saying in the [github conversation](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/4943) and this [conversation](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4897).

So my question is how is this inheritance work?

From what I understand about inheritance, there should be some control how the child variable be overwrite the parent variable. From the document, I believe it is through the variable `layout`. Then this should look like this;

```
declare A = apple 

include file.html > declare layout.A = orange

print A => apple
```

Other case is;

declare A = apple

include file.html > print A => apple

> declare A = orange

print A => orange

What is the point of having an argument in the include if the child `include` inheritances the value without explicitly tells it to.

also with the leak variables into the `include` child, would mean the child `include` is not isolated any more for the purpose of special case like it is [saying here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-parameters-to-includes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Includes and layouts are not the same.

While generating a site, Jekyll does a lot of things in a particular order.

- Read pages's datas
- Render liquid

  - make necessary `includes`
  - compute liquid tags and filters
- Render html in case the document is markdown
- Render layout

When it renders liquid :

```
=== page.html
include other.html

print a
assign: a = apple
print a

include other.html
=== end page.html
```

Becomes a pile of code which is processed like this :

```
=== page.html
  ====== other.html
  print a ------> nil
  assign: a = orange
  print a ------> orange
  ====== end other.html
print a ------> orange
assign: a = apple
print a ------> apple
  ====== other.html
  print a ------> apple
  assign: a = orange
  print a ------> orange
  ====== end other.html
=== end page.html
```

Liquid tags are executed exactly in the order they appear in code, and variables (the local variables assigned in page body, not the one in front matter that are *freezed* and cannot be changed) are global and can be overridden from page or any child include.

After this, it renders HTML if necessary, and "spits" page's `{{ content }}` in the layout that knows nothing about page's local variables and can only see page's variables defined in front matter.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, now it is much clearer what people are saying on GitHub about the code pattern. Instead of thinking each `include` as a separate entity or closure function, they just a small part of a larger piece and get render in before the layout.